# Change default view to view the highlighted row of a table instead of from the top?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, datatables

[image: table]

[image: table2]

I have a table that looks like this, built using https://datatables.net/, with around 100 rows or more. The highlighted row is saved whenever users click save and the highlight will stay there when they come back.

I want to default the view to see the highlighted row whenever the page loads. Right now, when I refresh the view comes back to the top of the table, even though the highlight maybe 50 rows below.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using javascript to call datatables' `row().scrollTo()` method on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var firstRow = table.rows('.selected')[0];
  firstRow.scrollTo(false);  //animate: false
});
```

This code isn't tested and probably won't run, it's just to give you an idea. More about `scrollTo()` [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().scrollTo()).